# How to return generic type in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

[In this simple example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCSAdtgK7pgC8YA3gD5gCWAJgFxhGkC2ARrgE5g6AX1QYc+APLkyFavSZswAZ3T9GRAOZDRqKKSIBjdIzhEwUOHAA8BADRhJAPgAUG2ewIBKVpLC1Uf0MzVTA4cnY-eRZ2d3IAOhZ49DgAZTUNTRcvUX9+XHRSfnNw9FRdYKJQuPRPEnIqWhiARgAGXUsbYlkHaXRZVxqvVCA) I get an assignment error:

```
type Input = {| id: number |}

type Output = {| id: string |}

function foo<I, O>(input: I):O  {

  // Flow states: Cannot assign object literal to `out` because object literal [1] is incompatible with `O`
  const out: O = {id: input.id.toString()}
  return out
}

const input: Input = {id:10}

foo<Input, Output>(input)
```

How to return the generic type O and keep flow happy?

Comment: Could you explain what's the point of generics here?

Comment: This implementation isn't going to work because inside `foo` you're already assuming the structure of `I` and `O`. When using generics, you need to think of `foo` as a reusable function that has no context of what types are going to passed in. If this function is for a specific use case, you probably don' t need to use generics and just define the types as `Input` and `Output`